# DataURI not showing in Website but is showing in console

Tags: image, svg, browser

I'm having a strange issue where images in an svg aren't rendering, however, I can see the image perfectly fine in the console. The issue is reproducible in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/f1rgy645/

I removed the actual dataUri from the example below to not spam the page.

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="9in" height="3.9375in" viewBox="0 0 9 3.9375">
  <!--Tally -->
  <!--Quote -->
  <!--Line ID -->
  <!--Background white-->
  <!--User -->
  <g transform="rotate(0 4.5 1.96875)" clip-path="url(#clip)">
        <!--Background: white.png-->
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="9" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 750">
          <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64, " x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate(0 375 500)"/>
        </svg>
        <!--Background: Halloween_Skeleton.png-->
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="9" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 4526 2727">
          <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64," x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate(0 1363.5 2263)"/>
        </svg>
  </g>

  <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <use xlink:href="#shape"/>
      </clipPath>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Looks like the DataURI is correct, so what is going on?

[image]

Comment: your jsfiddle is a blank white page?

Comment: The scaling/translation/viewBoxes you're using have placed the image(s) such that they aren't in the viewable area. Probably best to start again and build the scene you want one piece at a time, ensuring as you apply each element that the images are visible.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I thought that was the problem too but I fiddled with the dimensions a lot and I couldn't get it to show. Thoughts?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS, yes, that is the problem. But the image is visible in the console!

Comment: I fiddled with it and did get it to show so more perseverence is required I guess.